# "Are you stupid, or do you eat rocks?"

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

In Italian, we use the expression *Sei scemo o mangi sassi?* which can be literally translated as "Are you stupid, or do you eat rocks?" It is a way of saying "You are stupid."

What is the more idiomatic way of translating it?

Comment: Does "o" have a wider range of meanings than "or"? In English this implies that eating rocks is not stupid.

Comment: I'm Italian, having always lived in Northern Italy, and I've never heard such an expression. Where is it used?

Comment: @Paola, I never heard something similar, too, perhaps it can be a regional usage. For the record, I prefer: "Ci sei o ci fai?"

Comment: Many, probably most, idioms don't translate very well. Your choices are to translate literally and hope people get the idea, or to use a phrase that conveys a similar idea in the target language, even if it uses few of the same words.

Comment: @Parola I was born, raised, and I am still living in Brescia. It's a common expression I have heard more than once.

Comment: @Carlo_R. I would have had troubles trying to explain how the expression is used. Plus, I am never sure it's _Ci sei o ci fai?_ or _Lo sei o lo fai?_

Comment: @StoneyB Italian _or_ is exclusive: or one or the other. (At least that is in that sentence.)

Comment: @Jay I said _translate_ but I meant an equivalent English expression. I doubt English native speakers would understand "Are you stupid, or do you eat rocks?" but I am sure there is an equivalent expression where the person is asked to choose between two choices.

Comment: AFAIK this is not used in north-east of Italy, although I know people from Brescia that use it. Maybe is from that area? The "Ci sei o ci fai?" is much more common, although less funny.

Comment: A not terribly amusing but faithful idiom is: "Are you thick or what?" or "Are you thick in the head?" Used when the speaker is incredulous at the stupidity of the person in front of him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy enough to find sarcastic ways of telling someone they're stupid, but **translating** the Italian expression while keeping its sense and force is tricky.

The literal sense is not obvious to me. The only interpretation that suggests itself is that it contrasts innate stupidity with deliberately acquired stupidity, induced by eating rocks. If this is the case, then it falls in line with a well-known class of English-language insults:

> Are you naturally incompetent or did you have to practice?
>   You a natural-born bitch or you just tryin to piss me off?
>   Are you naturally stupid or did you take lessons?

---

ADD: This appears to be the sense of Carlo_R's version, "Ci sei o ci fai?", approximately "Is that who you are or are you just pretending?"

---

That leaves the "eat rocks" piece to deal with. As Messrs. Schwartz and Au observe, "rocks" are associated with stupidity in English—“dumb as a rock, as a box of rocks”, “head full of rocks”—but *eating* rocks would be taken as a symptom of stupidity, not a cause of it. Your translation would have to convey that causality explicitly:

> You naturally stupid or'd you eat rocks to get that way?

But that's still not entirely satisfactory. *Traduttore, traditore*. (The only Italian I completely understand!)

Comment: I think the Italian expression is giving a false choice; what is really saying is "Are you stupid, or are you stupid?" since eating rocks is not smart. The _funny_ part is seeing the people you asked that perplex and trying to understand what they should be answering, which would be mean they are stupid. Somebody could reply "I eat rocks." knowing exactly what the question means. Your first three expressions use the same mechanism: Asking people to choose between two choices _distract_ them from what you are saying.

Comment: AFAIK the word *tradittore* doesn't exist. You probably meant *traditore*, with one *t*.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ah, now I get it. In effect it's "Are you stupid or are you on the other hand stupid?"

Comment: @Bakuriu One {t} is what I had, and then I got nervous and went online - and the first three hits I got had {tt}, so I changed it. Makes sense: -dittore would be L *transdictor*, not *traditor*. I'll change it back.

Answer (score 4):

Any of the various ways English speakers tell people they are stupid will do. The best one depends on the contexts in which Italian speakers would use that particular idiom or the age and social status of the people speaking. You would want to pick the phrase English speakers would likely use to convey "you are stupid" in that same context.

Possible choices: "Dummy!", "Idiot!", "Are you really that stupid?", "You're dumber than a box of rocks", "Where were you when God gave out brains?", "Somewhere, a village is missing its idiot", "If all the village idiots left their villages and formed their own village of idiots, in that village *you* would be the village idiot", "You're a few cards short of a full deck", "if you were any stupider, I'd have to water you", and so on.

Comment: +1 for _Where were you when God handed out brains?_ As for _a few cards short of a full deck_, that reminds me of another kind of expression the might deserve its own paragraph: _not the brightest crayon in the box_ (or, _bulb in the chandelier_); _not the sharpest tack on the wall_ (or _tool in the shed,_ or _knife in the drawer_, etc.). Dozens more [here](http://askville.amazon.com/terms/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=5808702).

Comment: I like the "if all the village idiots left their village […]."

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent English expression is, "do you have rocks in your head?"

Answer (score 3):

I would say the closest to an English expression with the same connotations, would be something like:

> Are you trying to be stupid, or does it just come naturally?